# Play Enumeratee that counts and samples values from input Enumerator

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

I am interested in how to best implement something like that with Play's Iteratee library:

```
def sampleEvery[A](i: Int): Enumeratee[A, Int] = ???
```

such that given a stream of `A`s, the `Enumeratee` would count them and emit the current value for that counter every `i`, and then add the last value as well (if possible without repeating the value).

For example, `Enumerator('q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o').through(sampleEvery(3))` would yield something like `Enumerator(0,3,6,8)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an enumerator to hold the state of the current number of elements seen already, which they are not really designed to do. You can work around it by closing around a `var counter: Int` but you might (and should) think it is ugly. Anyways, below is an example that I believe has the behavior you are looking for using the scala repl

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def sampleEvery[A](i: Int): Enumeratee[A, Int] = {
  var counter: Int = 0
  Enumeratee.grouped[A](Iteratee.takeUpTo[A](i)) compose Enumeratee.map[Seq[A]]{seq => counter += seq.length; counter}
}

val e = Enumerator('q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o')
val promise = e.through(sampleEvery(3)).run(Iteratee.getChunks[Int])
Await.result(promise, 200 milliseconds)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
sampleEvery: [A](i: Int)play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee[A,Int]
e: play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[Char] = play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$$anon$19@5d9a1340
promise: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@65c78844
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9, 9)

scala>
```

If you are interested in something less closing-around-mutable-state (ugly), you could look into implementing this behavior in an iteratee where you can hold intermediate state.

Comment: As you guessed, I am really interested in a version not holding a state through a `var`. I tried but it looks like I can't wrap my head around the type signature involved in the `Enumeratee`.

Comment: Again, enumeratees are not designed for holding state. They are simply transformations of the data from a producer (`Enumerator[A]`) to a consumer (`Iteratee[B, V]`). Thus the type signature `Enumeratee[A, B]` means that it maps the input of type `A` to the output of type `B`. (`V` is the type of value that the `Iteratee` eventually produces). If you remove the `var counter` you can use `Enumeratee.map{_.length}` and create an enumerator that provides `Enumerator(3, 3, 3, 0)` and then collect this in your `Iteratee` and that would fold over this stream to produce your increasing values.

Comment: You could also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759548/creating-an-enumeratee-from-a-stateful-algorithm